# Get function in django rest framework does not work even though i explicitly say for permission to allow any

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I want to send my product category data to the frontend. this is my view function:

```py
class CategoryView(APIView):
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        permission_classes=[AllowAny]
        category=Category.objects.all()
        serializer=CategorySerializer(category, many=True)  
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

In the frontend i have this:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/Category/')
    .then(res=>setCategory(res?.data))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    .then(res=>console.log('category are'+res?.data))
  },[category])
```

Even though i have stated for permission to allow any, it still says 401 unauthorized error. why is this happening and how do i fix it?

Comment: You need to set `permission_classes` as a class attribute. Not inside the `get` function

Comment: but i have a post function as well which needs authentication to add new category.

Comment: http://localhost:8000/Category/ this api giving you response when u test in postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to put `permission_classes` outside of function itself, you could also try to provide an empty `authentication_classes` in order to override default ones.

Here is a final example:

```py
class CategoryView(APIView):
    permission_classes = []
    authentication_classes = []

    def get(self,request,format=None):
        category=Category.objects.all()
        serializer=CategorySerializer(category, many=True)  
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I did permission_classes = [AllowAny] for the view to get category and made a separate view that has permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] for adding more category. I couldn't figure out how to make both get and post in the same view.